# render same response to two select box from controller

Tags: jquery, grails, render, gsp

I have created cascading select as follows-

```
<td>Reference Table:</td>
<td><g:select name="tableCombo"
            noSelection="${['':message(code:'Select Table')]}"
            from="${result}" value="${tableName }"     onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'load',
             action:'getColumns', update:'columns', params:'\'tableCombo=\' + this.value')}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Constraint On 1:</td>
        <td><g:select name="columns" noSelection="${['':message(code:'Select Columns')]}" from="[]" /></td>
        <td>Constraint Value :
        </td>
        <td><g:textField name="columnValue" value="${enterVal }"     />   </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Constraint On 2:</td>
        <td><g:select name="columns2" noSelection="${['':message(code:'Select Columns')]}" from="[]" /></td>
        <td>Constraint Value :</td>
        <td><g:textField name="columnValue" value="${enterVal }" />
```

NOW i want to render and populate columns & columns2 both select box onchange tableCombo. but dont know how to render both from controller.

```
def getColumns = {
    def columns = GGWSchemaXref.executeQuery("select distinct p.columnname     from GGWSchemaXref p where p.tablename=:table",[table:params.tableCombo])
    render g.select(from:columns, name:"columns")
        }
```

PLEASE HELP ON THIS.

thanks

Comment: thanks for reply Alidad. you are right i want to update two select boxes (at a time) when first selectbox changes.   can i specify column & column2 both in update anyway (below)                   onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'load',
     action:'getColumns', update:'columns', params:'\'tableCombo=\' + this.value')}"/>
   
    I have used the template way.
    
   </td>

Comment: I dont think you can update more than one elements with "update". based on this jira http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4878. but you can write a javascript function to update the elements based on the response. instead of rendering your select from controller, return the required values in a map or in JSON then render them using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to populate the value of your two selects based on the value of the first select. I would suggest to return a JSON or render a template including a modal map including your result from your controller and render it on your views. 
Take a look at these two questions:

[how to populate 2nd Combobox(g:select) values on basis of 1st Combobox (g:select)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691175/how-to-populate-2nd-comboboxgselect-values-on-basis-of-1st-combobox-gselect)

[Grails: Load data on one ComboBox depending on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770765/grails-load-data-on-one-combobox-depending-on-another)

hope these helps

Comment: thanks Alidad. above both links are doing the same thing which i tried.My problem is how to pass two selectbox(at a time) name while update after calling remotefunction?