# Grails - NoSuchMethodException

Tags: grails

I just implemented a dynamic dropdown menu based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3771240/3691484, but now whenever I try to create an object based on the 2nd dropdown list, I get

```
|
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.Set.<init>()
Error |
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
Error |
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053),
```

basically the same error as https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10635. However, the solution listed in the JIRA doesn't seem to applicable to my case, as this is how my domain class is (Tag is the primary select box, subtag dynamically changes based on the tag selected)

```
class Tag {

static scaffolding = true

String template
String tagName


static hasMany = [subtags: Subtag]


String toString()
{
    "${tagName} - ${template}"
}

static constraints = {
    template(inList: ["Proposal", "Resume", "Training Manual"])
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is fixed in recent versions of Grails.  If you can still produce it with the latest 2.3.x release, please file a JIRA, but I don't think this is still a problem.